# Dúvida a respeito do método __dict__ em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dicionário

Bom, sou iniciante em programação Python e comecei estudar orientação a objetos.

Me deparei com o seguinte código, que por questão é bem simples.

```
class Pessoa:
    def __init__(self, nome, idade, altura):

        """Método construtor da classe Pessoa"""

        self.__nome = nome
        self.__idade = idade
        self.__altura = altura

pessoa1 = Pessoa('Fulano', 32, 1.86)

print(pessoa1.__dict__)
```

Tive o seguinte retorno:

```
{'_Pessoa__nome': 'Fulano', '_Pessoa__idade': 32, '_Pessoa__altura': 1.86}
```

Tem alguma forma de fazer essa saída ficar formatada da forma abaixo?

```
{'Nome': 'Fulano', 'Idade': 32, Altura': 1.86}
```

Eu falo isso por questões de visibilidade para o usuário.

Comment: Tem, lendo o dicionário e imprimindo do jeito que quiser.

Comment: Não seria melhor usar o método `__str__` do que utilizar o dicionário com `__dict__`?

Answer (score 3):

`__dict__` não é um método - é um atributo - e é a forma implementada, oficialmente, na linguagem de guardar atributos de instância nos objetos.

É um dicionário comum, e você pode usar qualquer código que operaria em um dicionário comum com o `__dict__` de uma instância.

O seu uso para acessar diretamente o conteúdo de atributos da instância não é encorajado - mesmo que não tenha efeitos colaterais. Via de regra, pode se dizer: se não precisar, não use diretamente `.__dict__`. (Há outras formas de se guardar valores de atributos nas instâncias - e como isso é feito pode ser customizado com o uso de `property` ou implementando-se `__setattr__` e `__getattribute__` personalizados, ou com o uso da funcionalidade de  `__slots__`, por exemplo.

Agora, o seu exemplo tem outra coisa que chama a atenção - é o uso dos dois `__` para prefixar seus atributos.
Bastante mateiral mais antigo de Python (e talvez algum material mais recente de quem tenha estudado nesse material antigo), costuma dizer que "usar dois '__' é o equivalente em Python de ter um atributo privado, como existe em outras linguagens de orientação a objeto". Essa afirmaçao, ou variações dela, estão essencialmente **erradas**.

O uso de dois `__` dispara sim  um efeito de renomeação automática de atributos e métodos, mas que mais provavelmente vai fazer você ter problemas do que te ajudar. Python simplesmente **não tem o conceito de atributos privados** sustentado pela linguagem em si - o que existe é a convenção de que atributos e métodos começados com um único `_` são privados, no sentido de que não devem ser usados exceto pelo mesmo projeto que implement a classe (e não por outros projetos que fazem uso daquela classe).

Em outras palavras: o uso de `__` para "atributos privados" está mais para uma funcionalidade criada por alguém que sentia falta de coisas privadas há mais de 25 anos, e acabou dando num beco sem saída que é pouquíssimo usado em projetos sérios.

**o que o uso de "__" faz**: (escrevo mais abaixo pra não ficar antes de coisas mais importantes) 
Sugiro *fortemente* que você agregue mais fontes de aprendizado da linguagem e não tente usar artificialmente atributos privados até entender bem como a linguagem funciona.

## Personalizando a representação de uma classe

Dito tudo isso, recomendo que você foque em funcionalidades e características realmente legais da linguagem - por exemplo, se você
criar o método especial `__repr__` ele será chamado para converter as
instâncias da sua classe para uma string para fins de visualização.

No seu caso, poderia ser assim:

```
class Pessoa:

    def __init__(self, nome, idade, altura):
        """Método construtor da classe Pessoa"""
        self.nome = nome
        self.idade = idade
        self.altura = altura

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Pessoa(nome={self.nome}, idade={self.idade}, altura={self.altura})"
```

COm isso, simplesmente `print(pessoa)` vai dar uma saída bem legível, como a que voce quer.

Se não quiser ficar repetindo isso pra cada classe e cada atributo, pode criar uma classe de base com essas funcionalidades - algo como:

```
class AutoAttributes:
    attrs = ()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """Método construtor genérico"""
        for attr in self.attrs:
            if attr in kwargs:
                setattr(attr, kwargs[attr])


    def __repr__(self):
        body = [f"{attr}={getattr(self, attr, None)}" for attr in self.attrs]
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({', '.join(body)})"


class Pessoa(AutoAttributes):

    attrs = ['nome', 'idade', 'altura']
```

E aí sim, vai estar estudando Python, e as partes boas de orientação a objeto - vendo como "herança" ajuda.

Mas depois de aprender e entender, Python 3.7 adicionar uma funcionalidade que faz o que faço na classe Base acima, e vai bem além, com várias outras facilidades para atributos automáticos - veja a documentação do módulo [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) (só existe a partir do Python 3.7)

## O que "__" faz de verdade:

(lembrando: por mais que seja um mecanismo "legal", não recomendo, pessoalmente, seu uso)

isso dispara um mecanismo de "name mangling" isso é "bagunça de nomes" de atributos e métodos. Esse é um mecanismo que acontece em tempo de compilação do arquivo ".py" (sim, Python é compilado para um 'bytecode' especial, assim como Java e C# - só que isso acontece num passo transparente para todos os usuários. Em Java e C# é necessário chamar um passo de compilação explícito, que hoje em dia é ocultado pelas IDEs que fazem tudo automaticamente). A finalidade de emular atributos privados com esse "name mangling" nunca foi de "não permitir que usuários de fora da classe possam acessar os atributos" - como é ensinado de forma resumida em aulas de O.O.  - isso não dá segurança nenhuma para nenhum código - é apenas para que, uma camada intermediária de uma hierarquia de classes complexas possa ter atributos que não vão ser sobre-escritos sem querer por subclasses que herdarem a mesma.

Vamos supor que eu tenha um projeto bem grande, e lá no meio, tenho uma classe que tem uma camada de validação com um método `validate` que vai validar a conexão com o banco de dados disponível para a instância. Em outro ponto na hierarquia de classes, eu vou ter uma outra classe para ser usada, que vai ter um método `validate` para validar os atributos mesmo (vamos supor que aí fosse checar regras para os atributos "nome", "idade" da sua pessoa). Num projeto único, com métodos não colaborativos, o `validate` dessa outra subclasse iria se sobrepor ao primeiro `validate` que nunca seria chamado. Se a convenção nesse projeto fosse usar sempre o `__`, então o método iria ter o nome real de `_NetworkMixin__validate` e o outro poderia ter acabar com o nome de `_AttributeMixn_validate` e os dois métodos poderiam ser chamados de forma independente.

Na prática, se notou que é preferível (1) não ter hierarquias de classes tão complexas, com centenas de métodos competindo entre si dentro de um mesmo objeto - e sim, objetos mais simples e genéricos que possam ser passados como parâmetros para outros que façam coisas tão distintos como "validar a conexão de rede". (2) usar herança colaborativa usando sempre o mecanismo de `super()` para chamar os métodos de todas as superclasses - todos os métodos que tem o mesmo nome são chamados se isso for bem feito.

Comment: Bom, tem pouco tempo que comecei a estudar Python, esse código não é meu, é de um material que estou estudando e nisso estava, "brincando" com o código.

Comment: como eu disse - algum material ou desatualizado, ou escrito por quem aprendeu de uma fonte nao atualizada e não se atualizou.